# Convert Flash animation to video

Tags: flash, mp4, mpeg, wmv

I have a Flash-file with some ActionScript code that loads an RSS-feed and animates the content. Now I need to convert that to a video file to use on an external display. Since the RSS-feed updates quite often, this needs to be automated and preferably run on Linux.

So far, I've only found tools to convert FLV to another video format, but that isn't exactly what I need.

Are there any tools available to do this or can it only be done manually through Adobe Flash?

Comment: Have you found a solution, since the question was post ?

Comment: No, sorry. Except for some pretty cumbersome workarounds involving launching a browser and recording the screen, but that's not really a viable solution, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export as a .mov file using the Flash UI via File -> Export -> Export Movie. This feature was pretty poor (and possibly nonexistant) in the previous versions of Flash, but I've noticed that it's improved significantly in the latter releases.

If your animation is ActionScript driven, then specify a time rather than "When last frame is reached" for the duration.

[image]

As for the automation, I'm not sure what you can do here; I don't think it's possible.

Comment: And if you don't have quicktime, can you just download a free version (just the player?) for this to work?

Comment: @bigp [Is this what you're looking for?](http://www.apple.com/au/quicktime/download/)